# Structure of Eclipse .PSF file

Tags: xml, eclipse

Can someone explain the structure of Eclipse .PSF file:

```
<project
  reference="1.0.1,file:///D:/Local/Projects/com.com.someproject.name/trunk,
  com.com.someproject.name,906854a82af700161d10d93c2fba605a;
  file:///D:/Local/Projects/com.com.someproject.name;
  file:///D:/Local/Projects/com.com.someproject.name;
</project>
```

Comment: The format of the `reference` depends on which source control repository provider is being used (SVN, GIT, CVS, ....)

Comment: @greg-449 I am using SVN.

Comment: As far as I know there is no documentation on the format that each provider uses. You would have to read the source code.